# Lenovo x390 Yoga Wifi Connected But No Internet

Tags: networking, wireless, bluetooth, internet, lenovo

I've been running Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS on my Lenovo X390 Yoga for 6 months daily without any issues. A few weeks ago I started having issues with wifi connections. I can successfully connect to my home wifi network and wifi tether to my phone wifi as well, but I am not able to access any internet. Running apt update shows it fails to connect to repos and anything through a browser doesn't work as well. However if I USB tether to my phone I'm able to get on the internet. Not sure if this is related but I've also noticed that my bluetooth keeps being disabled by default after I restart.

Comment: Since you can connect to your wifi, the drivers of your Ubuntu seem ok. Can you connect your phone to the same wifi and reach the internet? If not, your accesspoint (what you call wifi) has a problem...

Comment: all other devices on the network can access the internet fine

Comment: May be you have wrong DNS setting. Have you tried ping 8.8.8.8? Does this work?

Comment: pinging 8.8.8.8 does seem to work fine. Pinging any web address directly doesn't result in anything. I've also upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS hoping that might help but it had no affect.

Comment: I've found a temporary solution, running "sudo apt install --reinstall wpasupplicant" to reinstall wpasupplicant seems to fix it temporarily until my computer goes to sleep. Upon reboot browsing to websites seems to fail again, but running the command while USB tethering to my phone seems to fix it right away.